# No sunlight in kitchen

Tags: lighting, kitchens

My kitchen used to get plenty of sunlight through windows, but a building being constructed next to ours has completely blocked the sunlight from entering the kitchen. There is no proper ventilation apart from the windows. Because of this, molds start to develop very soon on the vegetables and lentils. Fruit flies emerge out of nowhere near the vessels even if they are clean. Kitchen is always moist. I am at loss how to handle this. Would love to hear some positive advice. Thanks.

Note: my kitchen is a mere room with no chimneys, no exhaust/ventilation fans. Just few shelves, a kitchen countertop with a stove on it, and a pair of double door windows beside it(through which plenty of sunlight came previous to building construction).

Comment: My question is how to overcome this situation? Any alternative methods to keep the kitchen warm? To keep things dry from preventing from getting moist attracting molds. This is becoming very challenging for me.

Comment: Add mirrors or windows in the internal walls if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have three different issues.  One is sunlight, which doesn't directly affect your problems, but could be remedied perhaps with something like this: http://sunpipe.monodraught.com/#new-sunpipes-by-monodraught (there are other brands and I've even seen DIY versions)

Next is fresh air, in your case it sounds like you're going to have to offset the building blocking your windows with fans to increase the airflow.  Maybe something as simple as a box fan in the window?

Lastly, humidity control... If a dehumidifier isn't practical for you, there are dessicants that are sold for camping, or boating. They're often just containers of silica gel that absorb moisture and can be dried out in the sun or a stove when they are "full".  Perhaps some of those where you store your goods that are prone to getting moldy.

Hope this is helpful...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable suggestions. I ll surely look into those and see which is feasible for me and use it . Thanks much again.

Comment: I strongly urge installing a stove hood/exhaust fan which vents to the outside if at all possible.  May cost a bit, but it not only lets you vent the room, but pulls cooking smells, smoke, etc. out of harm's way.

Comment: That's very useful suggestion. I ll have to see whether fixing those is possible in my kitchen arrangement. If it is , I can proceed. Thanks!.